# What is the role of chiral compensator?

Tags: supersymmetry, supergravity

When studying SUGRA inflation, I stumbled upon a notion of "chiral compensator". What is its role? I don't remember seeing it in Wess & Bagger textbook.

Comment: Stumbled upon where? Which page?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That paper deals with conformal supergravity, thus you need to consider a compensating multiplet to compensate the redundant conformal symmetries. In the first half of the paper, an off-shell chiral compensator is used.

In that paper, a chiral multiplet $S_0$ with conformal weight $w=1$ and chiral weight $c =1$ is used. The multiplet consists of a complex scalar $\Phi$, a Majorana fermion $P_L \Omega$ and an auxiliary scalar $F$. Setting $\Phi = M_{pl} = 1$ (see eq 2.7, they call the scalar $S_0$), fixes the dilatation symmetry of the conformal group, and $P_L \Omega = 0$ fixes the S-supersymmetry.